# Some tools are not working on Sample Aviary(PHOTO EDITOR) in Android L

Tags: android, android-library, aviary

I have integrated Aviary(PHOTO EDITOR) in my Application, when i launch Aviary Editor then some tools are not working(Effects, Frames, Stickers and Overlays).
And also stuck to get API key for aviary.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I suspect the vote on this came from a puppet account since the question is too vague to really be answerable, and it highly unlikely to be useful to anyone else. There, back to 0.

Comment: nope. it was quite useful to me. answer directed me towards the bug. what i have observed here is people criticize way more than they help. perhaps the reason being, criticism and flagging down is much easier than going ahead and doing some effort for helping a fella. pathetic mindset !

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.aviary.com/apps

please login in sdk and put the key and secret id showing at bottom, in this page there are two key and secret id ,first one used in iphone app and second is used to android app but in this page it shows only iphone icon but it's wrong. second key and secret used in your code. it works fine on android app .thanx